When did Sichon's Battle with the Moabites Take Place?
So the Jews fought Sichon in their last year or so in the desert; Bamidbar 21:26 then tells us that the territory they took "had belonged to Moab, but Sichon battled a previous [or "the first"] king of Moab and took it", and there's a famous poem about that battle.
Of course the Midrash says those "poets" were a young cursor-apprentice Bilaam and his father (Be'or & Son Hexes Inc.).
Do any sources give any chronologies as to when this happened -- how many years before the Jews arrived?
Things to consider:

It's a previous king of Moab, but the same Sichon. So it happened less-than-one-Sichon-lifespan ago. (Of course, sources differ on his lifespan...)

Bilaam's donkey says she's been around "since when you were", either when he first learned to ride, or when he first got into the cursing business; a donkey's lifespan is 30-ish years ... so if we follow the Midrash that Bilaam was one of the "bards", that would indicate it was no more than 30 years prior.



Also note that Bilaam only lived for 34 years (Sanhedrin 106b)

@User123 takka -- about the same lifespan as a donkey!

@User123 that's ridiculous. He was part of the plot to pharaoh to drown the newborn males, which was about 120 years prior

@Coreofreality Rashi at the top of Sanhedrin 106b notes that there are differing opinions in the Gemara itself. Rabbi Simai has the famous midrash about the plot; Rabbi Chanina has him short-lived. בר תלתין ותלת - ור"ח לית ליה דר' סימאי דאמר לעיל (עמוד א) שלשה היו באותה עצה דפרעה בלעם ואיוב ויתרו דלר' סימאי בלעם חיה יותר מן מאתים ועשר שנים

Rabbi Aryeh Kaplan zt"l never ceases to amaze me. In The Living Torah, he says Sefer HaYashar writes it was four years prior.
Thank you JoelK for finding the source in Sefer HaYashar:

ויהי בשנת שלושים ושש שנה לצאת בני ישראל ממצרים ויער ה' את סיחון מלך
האמורי ויערוך מלחמה ויצא להלחם את בני מואב
In the thirty-sixth year since the Jews left Egypt, G-d stirred up
Sichon, King of the Emori, and he waged war, going to attack the
Moabites.

That would be consistent with a "young-Bilaam" approach. In fact, that same page of Sefar HaYashar splits the difference between the "young-Bilaam" midrashim, and those about Bilaam advising Pharaoh to drown the firstborn. Sefer HaYashar identifies Be'or as son of Yanis, son of Bilaam-the-advisor-of-Pharaoh. So the advising-Pharaoh Bilaam was the great-grandfather and namesake of the cursing-Jews Bilaam!

Here's the relevant passage in Sefer HaYashar: ויהי בשנת שלושים ושש שנה לצאת בני ישראל ממצרים ויער ה' את סיחון מלך האמורי ויערוך מלחמה ויצא להלחם את בני מואב https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=30784&st=&pgnum=137

@JoelK Thank you! I'll incorporate that in. Note that Sefer HaYashar splits the difference between the 34-year-old Bilaam and the advising-Pharaoh Bilaam: the former was the curse-guy we encounter, while the latter was his great-grandfather and namesake!

I thought yesterday it might be in Yashar, it seems up that book's alley. Didn't get around to checking though.

B"H
"a donkey's lifespan is 30-ish years ."
This donkey was created during the six days of creation and lived for thousands of years (pirkei avos chapter 5).
It would have lived forever had the angel not killed it (Rashi parshas balak)
Gemara sotah says that Bilaam was part of the plot to pharaoh to drown the newborn males, which was about 120 years prior.
So it could have been any time

The mouth of the donkey was around since creation; which presumably means the physics/metaphysics required for this to happen later. Doesn't mean the donkey itself was around forever. Rashi simply says the angel killed the donkey so that people wouldn't point at the donkey and say "that's the one that shamed Bilaam"; I don't see where that implies forever. (In fact, if you look at the similar case of stoning livestock, we see it's not about forever.)

@Shalom a different midrash, and Rashi itself, says that the same donkey that Moshe rode on from the burning bush to Egypt is the same donkey that Avraham sattled during the binding of Yitzchak, and it's the same donkey that moshiach will be revealed on. In tana dvei rabbi Elazar it says that that donkey is the son of the donkey that was "created during the 6 days of creation" that Bilaam rode on
